# How to add to a mock repository

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am creating an app using MVC 4.

I have the following Mock repository

```
Mock<IProductRepository> mock = new Mock<IProductRepository>();
mock.Setup(m => m.Products).Returns(new List<Product>
{
    new Product { Name = "FootBall", Price=25 },
    new Product { Name = "Surf board", Price=179 },
    new Product { Name = "Running shoes", Price=25 },
}.AsQueryable());

ninjectKernel.Bind<IProductRepository>().ToConstant(mock.Object);
```

In my controler how can I add a new product to this repository?

public class ProductController : Controller
    {
        private IProductRepository repository;

```
    public ProductController(IProductRepository productRepository)
    {

        repository = productRepository;

    }

    public ViewResult List()
    {
        return View(repository.Products);
    }

    public ViewResult Add()
    {
       var newProduct = new Product
        {
            Name = "Sneakers", Price = 30
        };


      //how do I add this newProduct to the repository?

    }

}
```

I added the following to IProductRepository

```
 public interface IProductRepository
    {
        IQueryable<Product> Products();

        void AddProducts(Product product);
    }

 public class ProductRepository : IProductRepository
    {

        public IQueryable<Product> Products()
        {

           //how do I access the repo?


        }

        public void AddProducts(Product product)
        {


             //how do I access the repo?

        }
    }
```

Comment: what methods does `IProductRepository` have?

Comment: None at the moment, I have added two methods.. see code update.. but how do I create the concrete instance of them? how do I reference the repository?

Comment: Are you trying to implement a repository or write a test for your controller?

Comment: I am trying to implement a repository, but without using persistent data, has to be in memeory

Comment: i am trying to create an MVC application with in memeory data... is that even possible?

Comment: yeah it is,see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your controller you can just do this:

```
    public class ProductRepository : IProductRepository
    {
        List<Product> data = new List<Product>
        {
            new Product { Name = "FootBall", Price=25 },
            new Product { Name = "Surf board", Price=179 },
            new Product { Name = "Running shoes", Price=25 }
        };

        public IQueryable<Product> Products()
        {

          return this.data.AsQueryable();

        }

        public void AddProducts(Product product)
        {
            this.data.Add(product);
        }
    }
```

The mocking does not work if you want to modify the data, unless you kept a reference to the list somewhere and you accessed that list in the controller's `Add` method.

**Update**

To ensure you use the same repository configure the `ninjectKernel` to always return the same one.

`ninjectKernel.Bind<IProductRepository>().ToConstant(new ProductRepository())`

Comment: my bad, just call `AddProducts`

Comment: I've updated my answer, just have the list as a member of the repository.

Comment: Awesome, that works great.. but the data does not stay, as soon as I go to an action method to list the data, it does not get listed.  Is that because when I request an action method it creates a new repository?

Comment: It might be creating a new controller, try `ninjectKernel.Bind<IProductRepository>().ToConstant(new ProductRepository())`. That way it should always use the same repository when creating a new controller.

Comment: Awesome.. Thanks for that.. you are a gentleman and a scholar... works a treat.. so when does it actually create a new repo now? when the website stops? just curious

Comment: It will create a new repo when you `ninjectKernel` is re-initialized, so probably when the website is restarted.

Comment: Ned - any thoughts on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23032077/how-to-setup-with-navigation-properties

Comment: Yeah, I posted an answer as well.