# How to setup with navigation properties

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to set up a simple library application in MVC4

I have the following entities

```
public class Book
{
    public Book()
    {
        BorrowedBooks = new List<BorrowedBooks>();

    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }        
    public virtual ICollection<BorrowedBooks> BorrowedBooks { get; set; }
}
 public class Borrower
{
    public Borrower()
    {
        BorrowedBooks = new List<BorrowedBooks>();
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }


    public virtual ICollection<BorrowedBooks> BorrowedBooks { get; set; }
}
 public class BorrowedBooks
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public int BorrowerId { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateBorrowed { get; set; }

    public virtual Book Book { get; set; }
    public virtual Borrower Borrower { get; set; }

}
```

I have setup 2 repositories

```
 public class BookRepository : IBookRepository
    {
        private List<Book> books = new List<Book>
            {
                new Book { Id = 1, Title = "Queen of the road", Author = "Tricia Stringer", BorrowedBooks = new List<BorrowedBooks>{  new BorrowedBooks {BookId = 1, BorrowerId = 1, DateBorrowed = DateTime.Parse("26/03/2014")}} },
                new Book { Id = 2, Title = "Don't look now", Author = "Paul Jennings" },
                new Book { Id = 3, Title = "Too bold to die", Author = "Ian McPhedran" },
                new Book { Id = 4, Title = "The rosie project", Author = "Graeme Simson" },
                new Book { Id = 5, Title = "In great spirits", Author = "Archie Barwick" },
                new Book { Id = 6, Title = "The vale girl", Author = "Nelika Mcdonald" },
                new Book { Id = 7, Title = "Watching you", Author = "Michael Robotham" },
                new Book { Id = 8, Title = "Stillways", Author = "Steve Bisley" },
            };

        private List<BorrowedBooks> borrowedBooks = new List<BorrowedBooks>
            {
                new BorrowedBooks {BookId = 8, Book = new Book { Id = 8, Title = "Stillways", Author = "Steve Bisley" },   BorrowerId = 2,  DateBorrowed = DateTime.Parse("01/04/2014")},
                new BorrowedBooks {BookId = 6, BorrowerId = 4, DateBorrowed = DateTime.Parse("08/04/2014")},
                new BorrowedBooks {BookId = 2, BorrowerId = 4, DateBorrowed = DateTime.Parse("08/04/2014")},
                new BorrowedBooks {BookId = 1, BorrowerId = 1, DateBorrowed = DateTime.Parse("26/03/2014")},

            };

        public IEnumerable<Book> Search()
        {

            return books;

        }

    }



public class BorrowerRepository : IBorrowerRepository
    {
        private List<Borrower> borrowers = new List<Borrower>
            {
                new Borrower { Id = 1, Firstname = "John", Lastname = "Smith" },
                new Borrower { Id = 2, Firstname = "Mary", Lastname = "Jane" },
                new Borrower { Id = 3, Firstname = "Peter", Lastname = "Parker" },
                new Borrower { Id = 4, Firstname = "Eddie", Lastname = "Brock" },
            };


        public void Add(Borrower borrower)
        {
            this.borrowers.Add(borrower);
        }
    }
```

How do I link the properties together? ie in my BorrowerRepository search method, it return all the data, but the Book value is just an ID, how do I link it with the values from the book repository?

have I set up my navigation property wrong? or is it the way I have set up my Repository data?

Comment: You don't have `Search()` method in `BorrowerRepository`. Did you mean `BookRepository`?

Comment: Your entities seem to be set correctly. So most likely the problem is in the repository. But it's not very clear. From your code it seems that you are trying to create a database using `Entity Framework` with `Code first`. Is that correct? Because you don't have `Entity Framework` or something related to it in your question tags.

Comment: I am not using any databases, I just am trying to get a sample working without any databases.  I am trying to use in memory, rather than use persistence data

Comment: So do you have `Entity Framework` added to your project?

Comment: no..... is that the problem?

Comment: Yes, it's a problem. Generally the `Navigation properties` are used from `Entity Framework` to create the correct mapping between the entities and the database. Just find some tutorial on using Entity Framework with Code First, here is one - http://surajdeshpande.wordpress.com/2013/10/16/entity-framework-code-first-approach-example/

Comment: but I don't want to create a database....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve that is to add a static class to hold collections of your data in memory.
Then in each of your repositories you delegate any data related operation to the appropriate collections in the data store and you can use `Linq` to do your queries.

```
 public static class DataStore
{
    private static List<Book> books = new List<Book>
        {
            new Book { Id = 1, Title = "Queen of the road", Author = "Tricia Stringer", BorrowedBooks = new List<BorrowedBooks>{  new BorrowedBooks {BookId = 1, BorrowerId = 1, DateBorrowed = DateTime.Parse("26/03/2014")}} },
            new Book { Id = 2, Title = "Don't look now", Author = "Paul Jennings" },
            new Book { Id = 3, Title = "Too bold to die", Author = "Ian McPhedran" },
            new Book { Id = 4, Title = "The rosie project", Author = "Graeme Simson" },
            new Book { Id = 5, Title = "In great spirits", Author = "Archie Barwick" },
            new Book { Id = 6, Title = "The vale girl", Author = "Nelika Mcdonald" },
            new Book { Id = 7, Title = "Watching you", Author = "Michael Robotham" },
            new Book { Id = 8, Title = "Stillways", Author = "Steve Bisley" },
        };

    private static List<BorrowedBooks> borrowedBooks = new List<BorrowedBooks>
        {
            new BorrowedBooks {BookId = 8, Book = new Book { Id = 8, Title = "Stillways", Author = "Steve Bisley" },   BorrowerId = 2,  DateBorrowed = DateTime.Parse("01/04/2014")},
            new BorrowedBooks {BookId = 6, BorrowerId = 4, DateBorrowed = DateTime.Parse("08/04/2014")},
            new BorrowedBooks {BookId = 2, BorrowerId = 4, DateBorrowed = DateTime.Parse("08/04/2014")},
            new BorrowedBooks {BookId = 1, BorrowerId = 1, DateBorrowed = DateTime.Parse("26/03/2014")},

        };

    private static List<Borrower> borrowers = new List<Borrower>
        {
            new Borrower { Id = 1, Firstname = "John", Lastname = "Smith" },
            new Borrower { Id = 2, Firstname = "Mary", Lastname = "Jane" },
            new Borrower { Id = 3, Firstname = "Peter", Lastname = "Parker" },
            new Borrower { Id = 4, Firstname = "Eddie", Lastname = "Brock" },
        };

    public static List<Book> Books { get { return books; } }
    public static List<BorrowedBooks> BorrowedBooks { get { return borrowedBooks; } }
    public static List<Borrower> Borrowers { get { return borrowers; } }
}

public class BookRepository : IBookRepository
{
    public IEnumerable<Book> Search()
    {

        return DataStore.Books.Where (b => b.Author == "Paul Jennings");
    }
}

public class BorrowerRepository : IBorrowerRepository
{
    public void Add(Borrower borrower)
    {
        DataStore.Borrowers.Add(borrower);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ned - thanks.. we must think alike.. I did something similar... but have another issue with navigation... have a look at this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23033220/how-to-have-navigation-properties-without-a-database/23033422?noredirect=1#23033422