# How to have navigation properties without a database

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am building an app with NO persistence data.  So it will be in memory.

I have the following POCO entities

```
 public class Book
    {
        public Book()
        {
            BorrowedBooks = new List<BorrowedBooks>();

        }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Author { get; set; }        
        public virtual ICollection<BorrowedBooks> BorrowedBooks { get; set; }
    }
     public class Borrower
    {
        public Borrower()
        {
            BorrowedBooks = new List<BorrowedBooks>();
        }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Firstname { get; set; }
        public string Lastname { get; set; }


        public virtual ICollection<BorrowedBooks> BorrowedBooks { get; set; }
    }
     public class BorrowedBooks
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int BookId { get; set; }
        public int BorrowerId { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateBorrowed { get; set; }

        public virtual Book Book { get; set; }
        public virtual Borrower Borrower { get; set; }

    }
```

I have created a class that will populated some sample data

```
public class DemoData
    {
        static Book book1 =    new Book { Id = 1, Title = "Queen of the road", Author = "Tricia Stringer" };
        static Book book2 = new Book { Id = 2, Title = "Don't look now", Author = "Paul Jennings" };
        static Book book3 = new Book { Id = 3, Title = "Too bold to die", Author = "Ian McPhedran" };
        static Book book4 = new Book { Id = 4, Title = "The rosie project", Author = "Graeme Simson" };
        static Book book5 = new Book { Id = 5, Title = "In great spirits", Author = "Archie Barwick" };
        static Book book6 = new Book { Id = 6, Title = "The vale girl", Author = "Nelika Mcdonald" };
        static Book book7 = new Book { Id = 7, Title = "Watching you", Author = "Michael Robotham" };
        static Book book8 = new Book { Id = 8, Title = "Stillways", Author = "Steve Bisley" };


        static Borrower borrower1 = new Borrower { Id = 1, Firstname = "John", Lastname = "Smith" };
        static Borrower borrower2 = new Borrower { Id = 2, Firstname = "Mary", Lastname = "Jane" };
        static Borrower borrower3 = new Borrower { Id = 3, Firstname = "Peter", Lastname = "Parker" };
        static Borrower borrower4 = new Borrower { Id = 4, Firstname = "Eddie", Lastname = "Brock" };


        static BorrowedBooks borrowed1 = new BorrowedBooks { BookId = 8, Book = book8,  BorrowerId = 2, Borrower=borrower2, DateBorrowed = DateTime.Parse("01/04/2014") };
        static BorrowedBooks borrowed2 =   new BorrowedBooks {BookId = 6, Book = book6,  BorrowerId = 4, Borrower = borrower4, DateBorrowed = DateTime.Parse("08/04/2014")};
        static BorrowedBooks borrowed3 = new BorrowedBooks { BookId = 2, Book = book2, BorrowerId = 4, Borrower = borrower4, DateBorrowed = DateTime.Parse("08/04/2014") };
        static BorrowedBooks borrowed4 = new BorrowedBooks { BookId = 1, Book = book1, BorrowerId = 1, Borrower = borrower1, DateBorrowed = DateTime.Parse("26/03/2014") };

        public List<BorrowedBooks> borrowedBooks = new List<BorrowedBooks>
            {
                borrowed1, borrowed2, borrowed3, borrowed4

            };


        public List<Book> books = new List<Book>
            {
               book1, book2, book3, book4, book5, book6, book7, book8

            };

        private List<Borrower> borrowers = new List<Borrower>
            {
                borrower1, borrower2, borrower3, borrower4              
            };

    }
```

data access code

```
public class BookRepository : IBookRepository
    {

        private DemoData data = new DemoData();



        public bool Add(Book book)
        {
            try
            {
                this.data.books.Add(book);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }

        public bool BorrowBook(BorrowedBooks details)
        {

            try
            {
                this.data.borrowedBooks.Add(details);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return false;
            }

            return true;


        }

        public IEnumerable<Book> Search()
        {

            return data.books;

        }



    }
```

controller code

```
public class BookController : Controller
    {
        private IBookRepository _bookRepo;

        public BookController(IBookRepository bookRepo)
        {

            _bookRepo = bookRepo;
        }

        public ActionResult Search()
        {
            var test = _bookRepo.Search();

            return View(test);
        }
}
```

But when I get the data from the repository, the navigation properties are empty... what am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you show the code where you are accessing the data?

Comment: added the data access codes

Answer (score 1):

You need to fill collections for books in `DemoData`. If you don't set them yourself they are null. So in short if you don't use any persistence framework you must create relations from both sides.

For example for `book1` you'll need to add:

```
book1.BorrowedBooks.Add(borrowed4);
```

And so on for all collections in all entities in your in memory database.

Comment: when I used book1.BorrowedBooks.Add(borrowed4) it says is a field but used like a type.. and does not compile

Comment: You must put it somewhere where logic runs. For example add a constructor to `DemoData` and put it there.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to make your lists static in the `DemoData` class as well and remove the instance private members of `DemoData` from you repositories. That way all your repositories will use the same data.

```
public static class DemoData
{
    static Book book1 =    new Book { Id = 1, Title = "Queen of the road", Author = "Tricia Stringer" };
    static Book book2 = new Book { Id = 2, Title = "Don't look now", Author = "Paul Jennings" };
    static Book book3 = new Book { Id = 3, Title = "Too bold to die", Author = "Ian McPhedran" };
    static Book book4 = new Book { Id = 4, Title = "The rosie project", Author = "Graeme Simson" };
    static Book book5 = new Book { Id = 5, Title = "In great spirits", Author = "Archie Barwick" };
    static Book book6 = new Book { Id = 6, Title = "The vale girl", Author = "Nelika Mcdonald" };
    static Book book7 = new Book { Id = 7, Title = "Watching you", Author = "Michael Robotham" };
    static Book book8 = new Book { Id = 8, Title = "Stillways", Author = "Steve Bisley" };


    static Borrower borrower1 = new Borrower { Id = 1, Firstname = "John", Lastname = "Smith" };
    static Borrower borrower2 = new Borrower { Id = 2, Firstname = "Mary", Lastname = "Jane" };
    static Borrower borrower3 = new Borrower { Id = 3, Firstname = "Peter", Lastname = "Parker" };
    static Borrower borrower4 = new Borrower { Id = 4, Firstname = "Eddie", Lastname = "Brock" };


    static BorrowedBooks borrowed1 = new BorrowedBooks { BookId = 8, Book = book8,  BorrowerId = 2, Borrower=borrower2, DateBorrowed = DateTime.Parse("01/04/2014") };
    static BorrowedBooks borrowed2 =   new BorrowedBooks {BookId = 6, Book = book6,  BorrowerId = 4, Borrower = borrower4, DateBorrowed = DateTime.Parse("08/04/2014")};
    static BorrowedBooks borrowed3 = new BorrowedBooks { BookId = 2, Book = book2, BorrowerId = 4, Borrower = borrower4, DateBorrowed = DateTime.Parse("08/04/2014") };
    static BorrowedBooks borrowed4 = new BorrowedBooks { BookId = 1, Book = book1, BorrowerId = 1, Borrower = borrower1, DateBorrowed = DateTime.Parse("26/03/2014") };

    public static List<BorrowedBooks> borrowedBooks = new List<BorrowedBooks>
        {
            borrowed1, borrowed2, borrowed3, borrowed4

        };


    public static List<Book> books = new List<Book>
        {
           book1, book2, book3, book4, book5, book6, book7, book8

        };

    private static List<Borrower> borrowers = new List<Borrower>
        {
            borrower1, borrower2, borrower3, borrower4              
        };
}
```

Then in your book repository, you access via the static members rather than an instance field.

```
public class BookRepository : IBookRepository
{
    public bool Add(Book book)
    {
        try
        {
            DemoData.books.Add(book);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public bool BorrowBook(BorrowedBooks details)
    {

        try
        {
            DemoData.borrowedBooks.Add(details);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
```

Comment: The Collections will still be `null` because they are not set anywhere. See my answer.